# Explain plan statement in DB2 not working using shell script

Tags: unix, db2, sql-execution-plan

I have used the below statement in my script to get the explain plan for a stored procedure but its throwing error

```
a=`db2 -x "SELECT current timestamp FROM sysibm.sysdummy1"` 
c=`echo $a|cut -d"." -f1-2`
time_new="'$c%'"
db2exfmt -d ${DATABASE} -e ${DATABASE} -g -l -n -s ${SCHEMA_NAME} -o SP_explain_plan_${TIMESTAMP}.out -w ${time_new} -# 0 -v %
```

Its not able to read the timestamp correctly. Can someone help

Comment: "Can someone help"? I doubt that, not without you telling what the error is. It might help to print the value of `${time_new}`

Comment: Error Message =
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "2015" was found following "XPLAIN_TIME)
LIKE ''".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601


SQLCA
Size    = 136
SQLCODE = -104
Tokens  = 2015 þ XPLAIN_TIME) LIKE '' þ <space>
Function= SQLNP01F
RC      = 0x801A006D = -2145779603
Reason  = 0x0000 = 0
Reason2 = 0x0000 = 0
Line #  = -705
Warning flags =     this is the error i am getting.

Comment: Why do you need the timestamp? It looks like you are trying to get the current timestamp. If you specify "-1" you get the latest explain anyway.

Comment: but if i am running these command manually its working. But if its in script its not working.